# Про нове правило чергування І — Й

Tags: правопис, чергування

Шановні, чи не міг би хтось пояснити (чи порадити, до кого треба звернутися) теперішнє правило чергування І — Й?

У §12.3 попереднього «Правопису» було сказано, що «Чергування **І — Й** не буває… в) після паузи: *Щось такеє бачить око, **і** серце жде чогось (Шевченко)*».

Натомість у «Правописі 2019» читаємо: «§24.1. Щоб уникнути збігу букв, що позначають важкі для вимови приголосні звуки, та для досягнення милозвучності, на письмі вживаємо І в таких позиціях… 2) після паузи, що на письмі позначена крапкою, комою, крапкою з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словом або складом, які починає буква, що передає ПРИГОЛОСНИЙ звук: *Нема вже тієї хатини. **І** я в сивині, як у сні (Д. Павличко); Він, **і**мовірно, нічого не зробить*; 3) на початку речення».

Чи означає це, що тепер після паузи, що на письмі позначена комою, крапкою з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словом або складом, які починає буква, що передає ГОЛОСНИЙ звук, треба писати Й?
(Наприклад: *Минув рік, **й** ось*… Але: *Минув рік. **I** ось*…)

Comment: Якого року правопис Ви цитуєте, кажучи «чергування І — Й не буває…»?

Answer (score 2):

Основні настанови щодо написання «і» та «й» у правописах 2015 та 2019 однакові:

- [Правопис 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par12):

  > § 12. Чергування І — Й
  >
  > Сполучник і та початковий ненаголошений і в ряді випадків чергуються з и у тих же позиціях, що й у — в.
  >
  > 1. І вживається, щоб уникнути збігу приголосних, важких для вимови:
  >
  > а) після приголосного або паузи, що на письмі позначається крапкою, комою, крапкою з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словами з початковим приголосним звуком: Нема вже тієї хатини. І я в сивині, як у сні (Павличко); Вірю в пам’ять і серце людське (Б. Олійник);
  >
  > б) на початку речення: І долом геть собі село Понад водою простяглось (Шевченко); І приковують [гори] до себе очі, і ваблять у свою далечінь імлисту (Коцюбинський).
  >
  > 2. Й уживається, щоб уникнути збігу голосних:
  >
  > а) між голосними: У садку співали Ольга й Андрій; Оце й уся врода (Панас Мирний); Квітли вишні й одцвітали (Малицький);
  >
  > б) після голосного перед приголосним: Навчає баєчка великого й малого (Глібов); На траві й квітках росинки, шелестіння й гомін гілки, щебетання й пісня пташки (Щоголів).
- [Правопис 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=18):

  > § 24. Позиції вживання сполучниківі часток І, Й та І, Й на початку слів
  >
  > 1. Щоб  уникнути  збігу букв,  що  позначають  важкідля  вимови приголосні звуки, та для досягнення милозвучності, на письмі вживаємо і в таких позиціях:
  >
  > 1) між буквами  на  позначення приголосних: Вірю  в  пам’ять і серце людське (Б. Олійник); Він іде; Тут ідеться про народні звичаї;
  >
  > 2)  після паузи,  що  на  письмі  позначена крапкою,  комою,  крапкою  з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словом або складом, які починає буква, що передає приголосний звук: Нема вже тієї хатини. І я в сивині, як у сні (Д. Павличко); Він, імовірно, нічого не зробить;
  >
  > 3) на початку речення: І долом геть собі село Понад водою простяглось (Т. Шевченко); І приковують [гори] до себе очі, і ваблять у свою далечінь імлисту (М. Коцюбинський); Імовірне водопілля цього року.
  >
  > 2. Щоб уникнути збігу букв, що передають голосні, уживаємо й у таких позиціях:
  >
  > 1) між буквами на позначення голосних: У садку співали Ольга й Андрій; Оце й уся врода (Панас Мирний); Квітли вишні й одцвітали (Ф. Малицький);
  >
  > 2) між буквами, що передають голосний і приголосний: Навчає баєчка великого й малого (Л. Глібов); На траві й квітках росинки, шелестіння й гомін  гілки,  щебетання й пісня пташки (Я. Щоголів); Висока ймовірність захворіти; Вона йде; Високе ймення — патріот.

Тобто:

- І старий, і новий правопис кажуть, що на початку речення має бути «і»: «Минув рік. І ось…»
- Але: У старому правописі, як Ви правильно помітили, був також пункт про те, що «після паузи» може бути лише «і» (формально там сказано, що після паузи «чергування не буває», але фактично, здається, з цього можна зробити висновок, що рекомендувалося після паузи вживати «і»). Яка саме «паузи» мається на увазі, не зазначається, однак із контексту попередніх пунктів можна зробити висновок, що після багатьох видів розділових знаків у межах речення (коми, тире тощо) слід писати «і». При цьому новий правопис цього пункту не містить, і навпаки — містить примітку: «Трапляються відхилення від цих правил уживання і, й, що спричинено вимогами ритму або мовними вподобаннями автора». Отож можна зробити висновок, що старий правопис рекомендував «і» не лише на початку речень, а й після розділових знаків у межах речень, у той час як новий цього не регламентує, і навіть навпаки: містить «лазівку» для порушення попередніх пунктів.

Comment: Sasha, дякую. Після крапки пишеться **І**. Після коми перед приголосною теж пишеться **і**. А от після коми перед голосним звуком — так, як Ви написали, тобто тепер немає чіткої вказівки. (Раніше в пункті 3 було сказано, що «чергування **І — Й** *не буває*… після паузи». Тобто раніше писалося **і**.)

Comment: @Гість. (1) Не пишіть, будь ласка, коментарі у відповідях; відповіді мають бути у відповідях, а коментарі в коментарях; для коментування натискайте «add a comment». (2) Перепрошую, я помилився, я мав на думці, звісно, знак після паузи (коми, тире тощо), але приклад написав із крапкою (що підпало під пункт про початок речення — там завжди «і»); я виправив. (3) «Раніше» — це коли? Я зацитував фрагмент попереднього правопису (2015), і там сказано саме так, як я зацитував. У IV редакції (1993–1994) так само. Ви, мабуть, спираєтеся на якусь ще старішу редакцію правопису (можливо, 1945 чи 1960)?

Comment: Sasha, перепрошую, що пишу у відповіді, але в коментарях я не можу написати, бо не можу зареєструватися (сайт каже мені: «Could not complete signup - email address was not verified»). Ну бог з ним, більше не буду. Просто відповідаю на Ваше запитання: я теж мав на увазі попередній «Правопис 2015» http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par12 ; див. § 12, пункт 3:
*Чергування* **і — й** *не буває*:
а) при зіставленні понять: *Дні і ночі; Батьки і діти; Війна і мир*;
б) перед словом, що починається на **й**, **є**, **ї**, **ю**, **я**: *Ольга і Йосип — друзі; І раптом людська тінь майнула. Куд

Comment: @Гість, можливо на вашу пошту мав надійти лист, в якому треба було клацнути на посилання для верифікації.

Comment: @Гість, звісно, пишіть тоді як можете (краще писати як можете, ніж не писати ніяк) :). «Див. § 12, пункт 3» — ото я дурень, прямо перед очима воно було й не помітив. Так, Ви маєте рацію, цей пункт прибрали. Тобто (якщо я правильно розумію) можна було тільки «і», а тепер можна обидва варіанти. Треба буде мені переписати відповідь.

Comment: @Гість, я переписав відповідь.

Comment: А як правильно: "доставка і оплата" чи "доставка й оплата"?

Answer (score 1):

Привіт. Перепрошую, що не можу коментувати до попереднього допису, поки недостатньо репутації. Але, схоже, у мене це також тягне на окрему відповідь:)

У **правописі 2019** спростили пункт 3, оскільки **пункту 1.2** та **двох підпунктів пункту 2** достатньо для трактування:

**$24. Пункт 1.2:**

> Після приголосного або паузи, що на письмі позначена крапкою, комою, крапкою з комою, двокрапкою, крапками, перед словом або складом, які починає буква, що передає приголосний звук: Нема вже тієї хатини. І я в сивині, як у сні (Д. Павличко); Він, імовірно, нічого не зробить.

**$24. Пункт 2:**

> а) **Між голосними**: У садку співали Ольга й Андрій; Оце й уся врода (Панас Мирний); Квітли вишні й одцвітали (Малицький).
>
> б) **Після голосного перед приголосним**: Навчає баєчка великого й малого (Глібов); На траві й квітках росинки, шелестіння й гомін гілки, щебетання й пісня пташки (Щоголів).

Цікаво, що тире не вказане ні в першому, ні в другому випадку, хоче це також інтонаційна пауза. Але пункт 2 чітко вказує на обмеженіше вживання сполучника *й*.

Примітка до другого пункту стосується більше віршованої, пісенної чи театральної форми, а також випадків, коли автор не хоче нічого змінювати й користується принципом «я так бачу»:

> Трапляються відхилення від цих правил уживання і, й, що спричинено вимогами ритму або мовними вподобаннями автора.

Тож після знаків пунктуації (як і на початку речення) перед голосним використовуйте «і», адже це трактуватиметься як пауза або вживання сполучника після приголосного.

**$24. Пункт 3** не зовсім стосується саме вашого питання, але доповнює попередні правила та більше допомагає визначитися зі сполучником.